# How to unversion a Visual Studio Solution committed with AnkhSVN

Tags: svn, visual-studio-2012, ankhsvn

I am using VS2012, ASP.NET 4.5

I have tried an initial commit which failed. Some files seem to be committed ie have blue ticks. I would like to start over, so I need to unversion the current solution (several projects), and basically start again. I want the solution as I had it before I started to try and commit it to SVN.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Copy your folder to another location.
2. Delete the .svn folder at the root of that folder structure, if it exists.
3. Try adding and committing that folder.

If it doesn't work then you need to find out why not. Why didn't it work the first time?

Comment: I had a power failure, so the commit did not complete.

Comment: SHould I still have a .svn folder when using Ankhsvn?

Comment: Just found it at sibling level to project folder.

Comment: Just deleted .svn folder and it seems to have worked. I did not need to copy the folder to another location. All the ticks have gone in VS. Why do I need to copy the folder to another location?

Comment: Power failure, uh-oh :(  I just thought you might want to leave the original one there as a backup

Comment: Actually with power failure, there's a possibility that your repo is in a kind of limbo state (if the repo is on your machine that lost power). Better backup everything just in case it starts going unstable.

Comment: repo is online, so my concern is some form of partial initial commit. It provide an error message along the lines of incomplete, however a lot of the files were in the repo, and many blue ticks appeared in the solution, and all appeared fine, but there was this error message so I am suspicious. I am now reimporting the solution to a deleted out Trunk, and all is going well.

Comment: By the way how does one "ignore" folders, be they projects or project folders such as bin, using AnkhSVN?

Comment: No such thing as a partial commit in svn. All files are copied to the server and then committed to the repo, is an all our nothing affair. You may have a partial commit in the servers temp folder that could be removed, but you won't get half the files committed and half not.

Comment: I think you can right-click on the file/folder in Solution Explorer and there's an Ignore menu...

Comment: Starting to understand about this all or nothing thing. Basically like a DB commit, it is a transaction. I am starting over, I still have my source, just want to ensure my repository is in good shape. All good experience with AnkhSVN/SVN !! I have a horrible feeling that I may need to do this import again with the ignored folders set, as I believe you cannot ignore once versioned, or can you unversion a folder and remove that folder from the repo?

Comment: Now all imported and looking good. Many thanks. Could not find "Ignore" so will post as seperate question.